# How can I sort the postgres column with certain special characters?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I am trying to sort on a character column in a Postgres database:

```
Select column1 from table order by column1
```

Output

```
dir1 
dir2
dir3
#num1
t1
```

I want the sort to print `#num1` first the way sqlite does. Any ideas what I need to change in my query?

Comment: A collation issue? [postgres collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html)

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution would be to "disable" your collation setting for this sort:

```
WITH x(a) AS (VALUES
  ('dir1')
 ,('dir2')
 ,('dir3')
 ,('#num1')
 ,('t1')
 )
SELECT *
FROM   x
ORDER  BY a COLLATE "C";
```

[Ad-hoc Collation for individual expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later.

Most locales would ignore the leading `#` for sorting. If you switch to `"C"`, characters are effectively sorted by their byte values. This may or may not be what you want, though.

Many related questions, like here:
[PostgreSQL UTF-8 binary collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778714/postgresql-utf-8-binary-collation/7778904#7778904)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ASCII value of the ordered field:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table ORDER BY ascii(column1)
```

Special chars ASCII values are lower than letters ones.

Output

```
#num1
dir1 
dir2
dir3
t1
```

Answer (score 2):

A brute force version to put `#` on top in the sort order

```
SELECT column1 
  FROM table1 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(column1, 1) = '#' 
               THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, column1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/67e9e/1)** demo.

*This may not be exactly what you want*